# Uniform in GLSL disappears

Tags: java, opengl, glsl

I am stuck in programming my 3D Engine. I got a lot of shaders working and I just created a new one. But for some reason, my uniform variables show a weird behavior.

I know that if uniforms are not used the location of that variable will be set to -1. But I know that my uniform is being used. This is what I got atm. (That shader makes no sense but it should still work)

Vertex Shader:

```
#version 150

in vec3 position;
in vec2 texCoords;

out mat4 hilf;

uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
uniform mat4 viewMatrix;

uniform float radius;

void main(void){
    hilf = projectionMatrix;
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * vec4(position,1.0);
}
```

the location of "radius" is set to -1 (because it is not used). Same for the viewmatrix. But my location of my "projectionMatrix" is also set to -1! That makes no sense to me. Now comes the weirdest part; When I remove the line: `gl_Position = projectionMatrix * vec4(position,1.0);`, the projection matrix will have a location greater than -1.

My Java call looks like this:

```
location_projectionMatrix = super.getUniformLocation("projectionMatrix");
location_viewMatrix = super.getUniformLocation("viewMatrix");
location_radius = super.getUniformLocation("radius");

//-----------------
protected int getUniformLocation(String uniformName){
    return GL20.glGetUniformLocation(programID, uniformName);
}
```

Is this a bug? Did I miss anything? What is going on here?

Comment: Also show your opengl code.

Comment: Without your set/get location code this is just a guess: you are trying to set something (e.g. same location) twice.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are not using the variable `radius`, when you compile the shader, it gets omitted (optimized out). Hence the shader after compilation does not contain that variable. That is why the location is set to invalid value `-1`.

Use the radius in your shader within the `main` function and it will return a valid location value.